# Passing data between Knockout and jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, dialog

I have an input element within a grid. On `click` I'm opening a jQuery UI dialog, but I'm not able to pass values.

How can I do this?

```
<div id="basediv">
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach : palletList">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class='smallInput2 ui-keyboard-input ui-widget-content 
                        ui-corner-all' data-bind="value: parentRoll, click: openMyDialog">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="WDIV">
    <input data-bind="value: $parent.parentRoll">
</div>

self.openMyDialog = function () {
   $("#WDIV").dialog("open");
}
```

Comment: Can you try this `<input data-bind="value: parentRoll">` insted of  this `<input data-bind="value: $parent.parentRoll">` ?

Comment: No it did not work. Just browsing around I found this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jbustos/dBLeg/. Can anyone please see . Its near my requirement. Only thing is that I want to send name to and from dialog Please see the link

Comment: For me it is working. Can you check this? https://jsfiddle.net/ArunRajR/aw1vvf5r/1/

Comment: Div is not getting opened as modal dialog. I think something missing in fiddle code. Can you check and confirm

Comment: But, your problem was with pass the values right? Here the value is passing.

Comment: Yes. It passes between 2 inputs as done by you. But it does not pass when 1 input is on modal dialog

Comment: Can you check it now? https://jsfiddle.net/aw1vvf5r/2/

Comment: Excellent. Thats it. Thank you Arun.

Comment: Im newly using this stackoverflow. How can i mark it resolved by Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the problem with your `data-bind`. I have created a fiddler for you.

You can try this https://jsfiddle.net/aw1vvf5r/2/

Comment: Clicked tick and up arrow. This is what i needed.